# Market consistent valuation of a pension scheme with return smoothing

Tags: risk-free

Assume we have an insurance company that is valued under a risk-neutral probability measure. Further assume that the company, for simplicity, only has return smoothing based insurance. Assets return with the risk neutral rate while the insurance capital returns with the smoothing based return. The own funds are mutual and are used for return smoothing mechanisms among other things.

What discount rate should one use to do a market consistent valuation of the liabilities? The risk-free rate or the implied from the return smoothing? The different return processes of the general assets and insurance capital make me a bit confused which one should choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a pass-through investment vehicle that invests into various asset classes with different risk/return profiles. Assume now that this vehicle has no equity. The interest on these bonds, as well as WACC, as well as the weighted discount rate on its assets will be all the same.

Now imagine that the corporate structure is the same but the borrowings are guaranteed by a sovereign. In this case the interest will be equal to the risk free rate.

Comment: Does the situation change if the profit and loss from the business is moved into equity and then redistributed through the return smoothing mechanism? Also given that the shareholders are the insurees, ie a mutual company.

Comment: Return smoothing works well (for the benefactors) if they're able to reduce transparency. It is an age-old practice by diversified corporates trying to smooth the P in the P&L so that the business appears more stable and deserving of a lower WACC. But it eventually catches up on investors via XO items, write-downs etc.